# Defining BSpline in SciPy knowing its degree, control points, knots, and weights

Tags: python, scipy, bspline, step

I am trying o re-create a spline curve defined in STEP geometry (entity "B_SPLINE_CURVE_WITH_KNOTS") for later evaluation using SciPy, knowing its *degree*, *control points*, *knots*, and *weights*. If needed,I could also have spline starting and ednding point coordinates. I expect not all of those inputs are mandatory for the spline definition.

Class BSpline in SciPy requires *knots*, *spline coefficients* and *degree*. Obiously, what I miss here are spline coefficients. **Is there a simple way (e. g. using SciPy functions) to compute the *spline coefficients*, from inputs I have?**

If someone wanted me to be more speciffic, here are example data:

```
'knots': [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],  
'degree': 3,  
'weights': [4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0],  
'controlPointsCoords': [ 
[0.0, 37.5, -18.0],  
[0.0, 37.5, -18.11781],  
[0.0, 37.54686, -18.35337],  
[0.0, 37.74703,-18.65297],  
[0.0, 38.04663, -18.85314],  
[0.0, 38.28219, -18.9],  
[0.0, 38.4, -18.9]
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no canned scipy function for this. You'll need to implement the computation of coefficients given control points yourselves.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Can you push me a little bit in a right direction please? I found this: https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-coef.html , but I am not sure if this is what I need. I guess this is more like computation of basis functions, than coefficients alone...

Comment: I start from the Lyche and Morken lecture notes which are referenced in the BSpline docs (but I'm biased, obviously :-))

Answer (score -2):

You can try this python library: `geomdl`

```bash
> pip install geomdl
```

python script：

```py
curve = BSpline.Curve()
curve.degree = degree
curve.ctrlpts = controlPointsCoords
curve.weights = weights
curve.knotvector = knots
curve.delta = 1 / point_nums
coords = curve.evalpts
print(coords)
```

***PS：The `scipy` does not support "C" curves, so use `geomdl` to construct BSpline***